# sudo easy_install for SimpleITK not that easy

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, simpleitk

So... I've tried several ways to download SimpleITK (pip install) on Python but it's not working at all! (Here: [SimpleITK python 2.7.12 installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175699/simpleitk-python-2-7-12-installation-issue)) Now I'm using easy_install and I get this error:

```
Searching for simpleitk
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/simpleitk/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/simpleitk/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'simpleitk' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for simpleitk
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('simpleitk')
```

Apparently, it's some kind of certification issue that I have no idea how to overcome. :/ Heelp

**EDIT: FINALLY GOT IT TO WORK!**

With

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org SimpleITK
```

In sudo su mode

Comment: I tried running `pip install simpleitk` and I ran into no issues using python 2.7.12 and pip 9.0.1

Comment: I understand... The problem is that the computer I'm using has some kind of weird security bug. But I figured it out =)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your python was not compiled with SSL support. You can check this with the following command:

```
python -c 'import socket; print(hasattr(socket, "ssl"))'
```